# Как отделить виджеты от таблицы и придать ей определенную форму?

Tags: python, pyqt, qlayout, qtablewidget, qheaderview

Как разместить виджеты не друг на друга и сделать таблицу определенного размера?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import lxml.html
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import random
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QGridLayout, \
    QWidget, QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize, Qt
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QPixmap
from selenium import webdriver


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
 
        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(480, 80))             
        self.setWindowTitle("Работа с QTableWidget")    
        central_widget = QWidget(self)                  
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)           
 
        grid_layout = QGridLayout()             
        central_widget.setLayout(grid_layout)   
 
        table = QTableWidget(self)  
        table.setColumnCount(3)     
        table.setRowCount(1)        
        self.button = QPushButton("закрыть", self)
        self.button.move(350,170)
 
        # Устанавливаем заголовки таблицы
        table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["Header 1", "Header 2", "Header 3"])
 
        # Устанавливаем всплывающие подсказки на заголовки
        table.horizontalHeaderItem(0).setToolTip("356")
        table.horizontalHeaderItem(1).setToolTip("nuk ")
        table.horizontalHeaderItem(2).setToolTip("246")
 
        # Устанавливаем выравнивание на заголовки
        table.horizontalHeaderItem(0).setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft)
        table.horizontalHeaderItem(1).setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter)
        table.horizontalHeaderItem(2).setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignRight)
 
        # заполняем первую строку
        table.setItem(0, 0, QTableWidgetItem("количество"))
        table.setItem(0, 1, QTableWidgetItem("кто"))
        table.setItem(0, 2, QTableWidgetItem("время"))
 
        # делаем ресайз колонок по содержимому
        table.resizeColumnsToContents()
 
        grid_layout.addWidget(table, 0, 0)   # Добавляем таблицу в сетку
 
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
 
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: Если хотите определенный размер у таблицы, то есть  setFixedWidth/setFixedHeight/setFixedSize, пример: `table.setFixedWidth(300)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Или так:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QMainWindow, QGridLayout, QWidget, 
                             QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem, QPushButton, QHeaderView)
from PyQt5.QtCore    import QSize, Qt


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(480, 80))             
        self.setWindowTitle("Работа с QTableWidget")  

        central_widget = QWidget()                  
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)           

        grid_layout = QGridLayout()             
        central_widget.setLayout(grid_layout)   

        self.table = QTableWidget()  
        self.table.setColumnCount(3)     
        self.table.setRowCount(3) 

        self.button = QPushButton("закрыть") 
        #self.button.move(350,170)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.close)

        # Устанавливаем заголовки таблицы
        self.table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["Header 1", "Header 2", "Header 3"])
        self.table.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.Stretch)
        self.table.verticalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.Stretch)                   

        # Устанавливаем всплывающие подсказки на заголовки
        self.table.horizontalHeaderItem(0).setToolTip("356")
        self.table.horizontalHeaderItem(1).setToolTip("nuk ")
        self.table.horizontalHeaderItem(2).setToolTip("246")

        # Устанавливаем выравнивание на заголовки
        self.table.horizontalHeaderItem(0).setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft)
        self.table.horizontalHeaderItem(1).setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter)
        self.table.horizontalHeaderItem(2).setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignRight)

        # заполняем первую строку
        self.table.setItem(0, 0, QTableWidgetItem("количество"))
        self.table.setItem(0, 1, QTableWidgetItem("кто"))
        self.table.setItem(0, 2, QTableWidgetItem("время"))

        # делаем ресайз колонок по содержимому
        self.table.resizeColumnsToContents()

        grid_layout.addWidget(self.table,  0, 0)   # Добавляем таблицу в сетку
        grid_layout.addWidget(self.button, 0, 1)   # +++


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Раз начали использовать layout'ы, то продолжайте. Ручное указание положения виджета и его размеры очень неудобное и почти никогда не нужно:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(480, 80))
        self.setWindowTitle("Работа с QTableWidget")

        table = QTableWidget()
        table.setColumnCount(3)
        table.setRowCount(1)

        # Устанавливаем заголовки таблицы
        table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["Header 1", "Header 2", "Header 3"])

        # Устанавливаем всплывающие подсказки на заголовки
        table.horizontalHeaderItem(0).setToolTip("356")
        table.horizontalHeaderItem(1).setToolTip("nuk ")
        table.horizontalHeaderItem(2).setToolTip("246")

        # Устанавливаем выравнивание на заголовки
        table.horizontalHeaderItem(0).setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft)
        table.horizontalHeaderItem(1).setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter)
        table.horizontalHeaderItem(2).setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignRight)

        # заполняем первую строку
        table.setItem(0, 0, QTableWidgetItem("количество"))
        table.setItem(0, 1, QTableWidgetItem("кто"))
        table.setItem(0, 2, QTableWidgetItem("время"))

        # делаем ресайз колонок по содержимому
        table.resizeColumnsToContents()

        self.button = QPushButton("закрыть")

        # Или QHBoxLayout, или QGridLayout
        main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        main_layout.addWidget(table)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.button)

        central_widget = QWidget()
        central_widget.setLayout(main_layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Скриншот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]